# Password management/synchronization?

Tags: passwords, password-management

Is there a good enough service I could run on my own home (Linux) server that I could use for storing/accessing/synchronizing passwords so they could be available for me from multiple computers/places?

I'm thinking of something like [Xmarks BYOS](http://blog.xmarks.com/?p=1102) or [Firefox weave](https://mozillalabs.com/sync/) but that would not be only for browser passwords, but passwords in general? A place where I could put my SSH, FTP, OS, etc. passwords? Maybe something like [KeePassX](http://www.keepassx.org/) but synchronizable?

And that in the same time, all these passwords are on my own server instead of being somewhere in the cloud? Standalone service, webapp service, doesn't matter...

Suggestions?

Comment: @pootzko, not at all - this is not (yet ;) ) a dictatorship, there are 2 other mods, Meta site and chat room for discussion... I removed the tags based on discussions that were had previously, and according to my understanding of the tags and reading of the question. If you ever disagree with anything *any* of the mods do here - you definitely have ample recourse. If you think our ideas re tagging is wrong, join the discussion! The only thing I'm determined, is to keep the site orderly and useful for everyone. Then again, I *may* make mistakes, and *please* let me/us know when we do.

Comment: OK so I use Sticky Password ([www.stickypassword.com](http://www.stickypassword.com)) - they are offline for desktop, which is my preferred method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the mean time I found out that [clipperz community edition](http://www.clipperz.com/open_source/clipperz_community_edition) can be used as such a thing. It allows you to host it on your own server as a web service. Master password is first encrypted localy and then sent to your server. After you login, you get an interface, and a feature to directly login to other services from clipperz. Also supports one-time passphrases. More info [here](http://www.clipperz.com/security_privacy).

Answer (score 8):

[KeePass Password Safe](http://keepass.info/) is an open source solution you may want to check out. It is mainly designed for Windows but it can be ran from a Linux box, [details here](http://keepass.info/help/v2/setup.html#mono).

Comment: -1 The OP is specifically looking for a solution that is "synchronizable", and he specifically said not kepassx, which was/is a port of KeePass.

Comment: @Josh KeePass **is** ["synchronizable"](http://keepass.info/help/v2/sync.html) it also has some additional [plugins](http://www.keepass.info/plugins.html) to cover other sync/back-up scenarios.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know any tool, but you can save your passwords in text file and encrypt with your private key with pass-phrase so only you can access the file.

Answer (score 6):

One thing you could look at would be combining [git](http://git-scm.com/) and a password safe program like KeePass or Password Safe.  Gits useful as it works pretty well cross-platform and setting up and synchronizing data with it is pretty easy.

I use git for synchronizing files across multiple systems and it works pretty well.  One problem is that you'd need to make your server available from all the locations you want to synchronize from, which will likely mean exposing a service or VPN endpoint on the Internet.  Git runs over SSH by default so, if properly configured, it shouldn't pose too much of a risk.

Answer (score 4):

I use [1Password](https://1password.com/) on the Mac, it has support for macOS, iPhone, iPad, Windows and Android. It can use a DAV server or Wi-Fi to synchronize between clients.

Answer (score 4):

I use a combination of [Password Safe](http://passwordsafe.sourceforge.net/), which now has a Linux beta for storing and generating passwords. I combine that with running [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/) to synchronize the password database across multiple computers for me at the same time. Works like a charm for me.

Answer (score 1):

(cross posting from another [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/754/921#921) geared for corporate users)

I've worked with "Secret Server" at http://www.thycotic.com/ .  I can provision a single password and share it among as many or as few individuals as I want.

There is an audit trail, and a great search functionality built into the web application.  There is also an online "cloud" version of the application that is free for one user.

You can create a new secret for each device you own, and add your own as needed:

[image: Security Choices]

All access to this database is secured by local, or Active Directory credentials.  If you choose to do so, you can have seamless login (SSO) to access the database for the currently logged in user over Kerberos/NTLM.

Overall, I think this is a good choice for a team, and general repository for corporate security information.

Comment: Sorry, but a Password manger site that redirects all its HTTPS traffic to HTTP doesn't look trustworthy.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

- [Dashlane](https://www.dashlane.com/)
- [1Password](https://1password.com/)
- [LastPass](https://www.lastpass.com/)
- and [similar](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/754/11825)

Most of them support password management and synchronization, so you can share your passwords for multiple devices.

See also:

- [How safe are password managers like LastPass?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/45170/11825)
- [Security analysis of Dashlane](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/74656/11825)